# Equal but not greater-or-equal?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Сomparing anything with `undefined` has been discussed many times, but today I had to compare items in arrays and, at some point, items in the array could be `undefined` and I was curious how they will compare to each other. I found that `undefined == undefined` is `true`, but at the same time `undefined >= undefined` is not `true`. Wait a second, if something is equal, then greater-or-equal also mean to be true? That is how logic works!

I can accept anything that ECMA Standard is saying, I believe those guys are sane and have a good reason for everything. But what on the earth could be a reason for this comparison behavior? If I was implementing `undefined` I would return `undefined` for any comparison that has `undefined` as an operand. But they choose to return `boolean`, and then why the results are like this?

Now I think the best solution is just to handle any appearance of `undefined` in a special way with multiple of `if` statements.

```
    undefined === undefined: true
    undefined == undefined: true

    undefined !== undefined: false
    undefined != undefined: false
    undefined < undefined: false
    undefined > undefined: false
    undefined <= undefined: false
    undefined >= undefined: false
```

Comment: The ECMA Standard describes and standardizes the existing behavior of the quirky language that is JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting... Strangely enough `null >= null` returns true.

Comment: I think we'll need to know how exactly these comparison are implemented :) +1, interested.

Comment: If you intend to use `==` instead of `===` and other comparisons that do type conversions, then you have to be able to understand how all the various type conversions are going to work which is fairly complicated.

Comment: Does comparison of two `undefined` implies type conversion? What type they are converted to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what on earth could be the reason for this comparison behavior?

The [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.io/) specification was not written to describe how JavaScript *should* work, it was written to describe how JavaScript *actually* works.

The language was implemented rapidly in Netscape Navigator, and contained many "bugs" such as this, which were then copied in IE's implementation. Eventually, ECMAScript was standardized, but not until after JavaScript existed in the wild. Standardizing any language that's already being used requires a certain amount of backwards compatibility.

`<=` and `>=` diverge from `==` simply because [the standard says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8). The standard says so because that was how they were implemented initially.